# Does Service Bus for Windows Server (Service Bus 1.0 Beta) support relay functionality?

Tags: servicebus

If it supports, is the API exactly similar to the  public cloud based Azure Servicebus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. Relay is scheduled for a later release. That's why we call this release "Service Bus messaging engine" in the fine print.

Clemens

Comment: Just Came to know, the upcoming AzurePack includes this feature.

Comment: No, it does not. The integration with the Azure Pack (portal etc) trumped inclusion of the Relay in terms of priority.

Answer (score 0):

Just Came to know, the upcoming AzurePack includes this feature.