# Relay binding not working for Window Server Service Bus 1.1

Tags: wcf, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I have installed  Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 (Not Azure Service Bus) that is having a default namespace.
I have downloded the sample from 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Relayed-Messaging-Bindings-ca039161
and change the following code to generate the token.

```
var machineName = Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).HostName;
        var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(WindowsUsername, WindowsPassword, WindowsDomain);


        string serviceNamespace = "ServiceBusDefaultNamespace";


        // The TransportClientEndpointBehavior specifies the Service Bus credentials for a particular endpoint
        var stsUris = new List<Uri> { new Uri(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://{0}:9355/", machineName)) };
        TransportClientEndpointBehavior relayCredentials = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior
        {
            TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateOAuthTokenProvider(stsUris, networkCredential)
        };

        //TransportClientEndpointBehavior relayCredentials = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
        //relayCredentials.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName, issuerSecret);    

        Uri address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "HelloService");
```

But it is throwing the following error
"**Unable to reach servicebusdefaultnamespace.servicebus.windows.net via TCP (9351, 9352) or HTTP (80, 443)**"

I have also tried the same sample with BasicHTTPRelayBinding,But that doesn't work.

Do i need to do some other configuration for relay binding 
Please suggest !!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Service Bus Relay features are NOT available on Service Bus 1.1 for Windows Server. It is only available in Azure Service Bus.

Comment: Could you please provide any microsoft link for the above statement.

Comment: @RJ the official docs do not include Relay support: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193027.aspx

Comment: This question also covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644262/does-service-bus-for-windows-server-service-bus-1-0-beta-support-relay-functio